# Equivalent definition of uniform convexity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is said to be uniformly convex if the following is satisfied:
For $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $x,y\in X, \|x\|, \|y\|\leq 1$, $\|x-y\|\geq \epsilon \Rightarrow \|x+y\|\leq 2(1-\delta)$.

I would like to show that this is equivalent to the following:

For $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $\|x+\zeta y\|\leq1\forall \zeta\in [-1,1]$ and $\|y\|\geq \epsilon\Rightarrow \|x\|\leq 1-\delta$.

The first definition clearly implies the second, for if for $\epsilon>0$, 
$\|y\|\geq \epsilon$ and if $\|x+y\|\leq 1$ and $\|x-y\|\leq 1$, by the first definition of uniform convexity, $\exists \delta>0$ such that
 $\|(x+y)+(x-y)\|\leq 2(1-\delta)\Rightarrow \|x\|\leq 1-\delta$.

To prove that the second definition implies the first, here is what I have tried:

Suppose $\epsilon>0$ and $\|x\|\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1$ with $\|x-y\|\geq \epsilon$. Let $\tilde{x}=\frac{x+y}{4}$ and $\tilde{y}=\frac{x-y}{4}$.

Then for $\zeta\in [-1,1], \|\tilde{x}+\zeta \tilde{y}\|=\frac{1}{4}\|(1+\zeta)x+(1-\zeta)y\|\leq \frac{1}{4}(1+|\zeta|)\|x+y\|\leq 1$, and $\|\tilde{y}\|\geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}$.

By the second definition, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\|\tilde{x}\|\leq1-\delta$, i.e. $\|x+y\|\leq 4(1-\delta).$

What I require, however, is $\|x+y\|\leq 2(1-\delta).$

I would appreciate a hint on how to proceed!

Comment: I'm confused by the second definition. Where does the $y$ come from? Also, for your choices of $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$, I can't really see why you've chosen a denominator of $4$. What would be violated if you chose the denominator to be $2$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ belong to $X$ with $y$ satisfying $\|y\|\geq \epsilon$ and $\|x+\zeta y\|\leq 1 \forall \zeta \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|\zeta|\leq 1$.

Comment: The choice of denominator 4 is so that the inequality $\|\tilde{x}+\zeta \tilde{y}\|\leq 1$ is satisfied. Is that possible without the 4?

Comment: So, if I may, what you're saying is $$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall y \in X, (\|y\| \ge \varepsilon \text{ and } (\forall \zeta \in [-1, 1], \|x + \zeta y\| \le 1) \implies \|x\| \le 1 - \delta)$$ Is that correct? If so, that's quite a mouthful!

Comment: Yes, that's right! This comes from the definition used for 'complex uniform convexity' with the $\zeta\in [-1,1]$ replaced by $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\zeta|\leq 1$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see why you've chosen $4$, but I think $2$ would suffice. If we changed the denominator to $2$, we would have,$$\bar{x} + \zeta \bar{y} = \frac{1 + \zeta}{2}x + \frac{1 - \zeta}{2}y,$$ which is a convex combination of $x$ and $y$, so it should still be in the unit ball.

Comment: Oh right, thank you very much!